# Understanding the ideal generated by a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So my class on ring theory recently began, and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding ideals that are generated by polynomials. For an arbitrary ring, I know the definition of such an ideal, that is, for $R$ a ring and $a \in R$, $(a) = \{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_ias_i \mid r_i,s_i \in R \}$. So, then, this set is essentially just all the possible sums of different combinations of $r_ias_i$? Say, for $n=1$, $r_1as_1 \in (a)$, where $r_1,s_1$ just "run through" all the elements in $R$?

Specifically, I had a previous homework problem concerning the following ring of polynomials:
$R = [\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}](t)$. I know what this means as a set, but I had trouble understanding this ideal: $f = f(t) = t^2 + t + 1 \in R$ and the ideal being $(f)$. The question was regarding $R/(f)$, which I know is the set $\{r + (f) \mid r \in R \}$, but I didn't even know where to start due to my lack of understanding of $(f)$. Any help would in understanding would be welcomed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put in simple words,

> In any ring $R$ (with unit!), the principle ideal $(a)$ generated by $a\in R$ consists of nothing but the *multiples* of $a$.

I give here just a heuristic:

I like to think of the quotient ring $R/(a)$ as having the *same* elements of $R$ but the *equality is modified* so that all elements of $(a)$ be equal to zero in the quotient. Observe that it is enough to require $a=0$, because $ras=0$ and $\sum r_ias_i=0$ already follows by the properties of equality.

In the case of polynomial ring, a factor like $R[t]/(f)$ with, say $f=t^n-a_{n-1}t^{n-1}-\dots-a_1t-a_0$ will always be represented by the set of polynomials of degree $<n$, because *in the quotient ring* we have
$$t^n=a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\dots+a_1t+a_0$$
So that, any time a $t^n$ appears, it *can be replaced* by a degree $<n$ polynomial in $R[t]/(f)$.

Comment: Ah yes yes yes! Thank you very much. Thinking in the same manner as the integers modulo $n$, it makes sense that polynomials of degree $n$ for a generic $n$-degree polynomial are congruent to $0$ in the factor ring with the ideal generated by said polynomial! At least, that's how I understood it. =]

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 10):

When the ring is commutative,  *as in your case*, things are way simpler and easier:

$$\forall\,a\in R\;,\;\;(a):=\{ra\;;\;r\in R\}$$

And thus in your very particular case, the ideal generated by a polynomial $\;f(x)\in R[x]\;$ is just the set of all products of $\;f\;$ by elements of $\;R[x]\;$ .

Comment: Thank you very much =] Now $(f)$ makes a bit more sense to me. But say the ring wasn't commutative. Would my interpretation of the set in the first paragraph be correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the ideal generated by a polynomial $f(x)$ be the the set of all products of $f$ by elements of $R[x]$ instead of $R$? I don't understand, can you please explain? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @John11 Of course, that was just a typo. Edited and thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I wasn't sure as I just started learning about ideals.

Answer (score 6):

A two-sided ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is naturally the kernel of the surjective homomorphism
$$
R \twoheadrightarrow R/I.
$$

Take your example, where $R = \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}[t]$ and $I = (f) = (t^2 + t + 1)$.  In the quotient (the image of the map), the polynomial $f$ is identified with $0$.  But if $f = 0$, then $af = a0 = 0$ and $fb = 0b = 0$ for any $a, b \in R$.  The fact that the ideal must be closed under multiplication by any element in the ring on either side is forced by the desire for the ideal to be a kernel.

Since $t^2 + t + 1 = 0$ in $R/I$, any time that you see $t^2$, you can replace it by $-(t + 1)$ or just $t + 1$, as the ground field is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

Try working out the sum $(at + b) + (ct + d)$ and product $(at + b)(ct + d)$ of two generic elements in $R/I$ to get a sense of the structure of this ring.  *Hint:  it's not very big.*

Comment: Alright thank you! Your answer and the other two helped me understand this a lot better. I'll work out a few other examples with this new-found understanding in hopes to master it